# dlclose does not close library open file handles

Tags: c, dlopen

I am dynamically loading a library with `dlopen`, then closing it with `dlclose`. I expected all library resources to be freed once `dlclose` completed, but there are still open file descriptors from the library after the `dlclose` call. I am wondering how to make sure a library is unloaded in the middle of program execution, such that it cleans up all of its resources.

My code is below:

```
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_PATH_LENGTH         80

int deviceQ()
{
    cl_int ret;
    void * libHandle = dlopen("/usr/lib64/libOpenCL.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    cl_int (* clGetPlatformIDs)(cl_uint, cl_platform_id*, cl_uint*) = dlsym(
            libHandle, "clGetPlatformIDs"
    );
    cl_int (* clGetDeviceIDs)(cl_platform_id, cl_device_type, cl_uint, cl_device_id*, cl_uint*) =
        dlsym(libHandle, "clGetDeviceIDs");
    /********************** PREAMBLE **************************************/
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;

    ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        perror("Failed to get platform IDs");
    } else if (ret_num_platforms != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Number of platforms returned is %d\n", ret_num_platforms);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Read platform IDs\n");

    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device_id,
        &ret_num_devices);
    if (ret != CL_SUCCESS) {
        perror("Failed to get device IDs");
    } else if (ret_num_devices != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Number of returned devices is %d\n", ret_num_devices);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Read device IDs\n");
    /********************** PREAMBLE **************************************/

    /***************** RELEASE AND FREE ****************************/
    dlclose(libHandle);
    /***************** RELEASE AND FREE ****************************/

    return 0;
}

size_t closeFileDescriptors(void ** arr) {
    // step 1 - get PID
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    //printf("PID is %d\n", pid);

    char path[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
    memset(path, '\0', MAX_PATH_LENGTH);
    sprintf(path, "/proc/%d/fd", pid);

    int fd;
    DIR * d = opendir(path);
    struct dirent *dir;
    struct stat s;
    char dirPath[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];
    char realPath[MAX_PATH_LENGTH];

    size_t index = 0;

    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 && 
                strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0) {
                fd = atoi(dir->d_name);

                if (fstat(fd, &s) != 0) {
                    perror("fstat failed");
                }
                memset(dirPath, '\0', MAX_PATH_LENGTH);
                strcpy(dirPath, path);
                strcat(dirPath, "/");
                strcat(dirPath, dir->d_name);

                #ifdef S_IFLNK
                if (s.st_mode & S_IFLNK) {
                #else
                if (S_ISLNK(s.st_mode)) {
                #endif
                    memset(realPath, '\0', MAX_PATH_LENGTH);
                    #ifdef readlink
                    readlink(dirPath, realPath, MAX_PATH_LENGTH);
                    printf("%s -> %s\n", dirPath, realPath);
                    #else
                    printf("[readlink not defined] %s\n", dirPath);
                    #endif
                } else {
                    printf("Not link: %s (proceeding anyway)\n", dirPath);
                    //printf("Not link: %s (ignoring)\n", dirPath);
                    //continue;
                }

                if (fd > 2) {
                    //int fdFlags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFD);
                    int fdFlags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL);
                    if (fdFlags == -1) {
                        perror("fcntl failed");
                    }
                    //off_t offset = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
                    off_t offset = 0;
                    if (offset == -1) {
                        perror("lseek failed");
                    }
                    if (arr != NULL) {
                        /*
                        arr[index] = (fileData *) malloc(sizeof (fileData));
                        arr[index]->flags = fdFlags;
                        arr[index]->offset = offset;
                        arr[index]->fd = fd;
                        strcpy(arr[index]->fdPath, realPath);*/
                    }
                    index++;

                    // ignore stdin, stdout, stderr
                    printf("Closing FD %d (flags %d, offset %zd)\n", 
                            fd, fdFlags, offset);
                    close(fd);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir(d);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open directory %s\n", path);
    }
    return index;
}

int main () {
    deviceQ();

    printf("=> Closing open file descriptors\n");
    closeFileDescriptors (NULL);

    deviceQ();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. You have to get the module to tidy up. Only it knows how to do it.

Comment: Why do you bother about releasing OpenCL things? It might practically not matter a lot.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Because after the first `deviceQ` call, the entire program will be (in future work) migrated to different hardware at runtime, so I need OpenCL to re-initialize its data structures.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how do I do that?

Comment: Did you read *carefully* the documentation of your particular *OpenCL* implementation, and the entire OpenCL standard API?

Comment: Well, you have to follow the rules of the library. Whatever they are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong. When you call [dlclose(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlclose.3.html), only the "plugin" (actually shared object) is "closed" (actually, *may be* `munmap`-ed), but not the resources (in particular the file descriptors, and possibly heap allocated memory) it has used.

In addition, on Linux specifically, `dlclose` is calling the so-called destructor functions of the plugin (those declared with `__attribute__((destructor))`, read about [function attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) in GCC).

If you are coding a shared library, you might design it so that *some* resources are released at `dlclose` time (by having appropriate finalizations run thru *destructor* functions). In general, it is not easily possible (and it should be a documented convention).

Resources like address space in virtual memory (obtained by [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) etc...) and file descriptors (obtained by [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html), [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) etc etc...) are global (and common) to the entire [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29).
So it would be possible (and legitimate, if documented) to acquire some resource (e.g. open some file descriptor) in one shared library and to release it in another one (or in the main program).

Since a resource "belongs" to the entire process, it makes no sense to speak of releasing the resources acquired by a library.

So your `closeFileDescriptors`  is quite probably a huge mistake (and it probably leaks some other resources).

<sup>(IIRC, OpenCL API has some way to release its resources, e.g. devices, contexts, kernels, etc.... But I forgot the *ugly* details; see `clReleaseContext`, `clReleaseMemObject` and many more, including some implementation specific ones.)</sup>

Reading more about [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) would probably widen your mind.

Read also Drepper's paper: [*How To Write a Shared Library*](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) & [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)

If you absolutely need to release OpenCL related resources early, a more sensible way might be to start a different child process dedicated to OpenCL things, and use clever [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) mechanisms (e.g. [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html), etc...) then terminate (properly) that child process once your OpenCL stuff is done. You take advantage of the fact that the kernel is cleaning all the resources used by a defunct process (don't forget to `wait`... it -e.g. using [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)- to avoid having [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)). If you are not familiar with all that, read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) first.

Comment: Is there any way  to force the library to unload and clean up all the resources it has allocated for itself including any `mmap` regions and open file descriptors?

Comment: No, because such resources are global to the process.

Comment: Is there any way to get a list of these resources, then manually de-allocate them? In particular, libOpenCL makes several `open` calls on `/dev/nvidia0` and memory maps a bunch of regions. Is there any way to automatically munmap that as part of cleanup?

Comment: No, there is no way. You should read the documentation of your OpenCL library.